# Wacom Finger touch problem in 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-touch, wacom, xinput

my laptop pen and eraser works well, but its Finger touch does not work.

```
xinput --list |grep Wacom
Wacom Serial Penabled 2FG Touchscreen Finger touch  id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
Wacom Serial Penabled 2FG Touchscreen Pen eraser    id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
Wacom Serial Penabled 2FG Touchscreen Pen stylus    id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]



uname -r: 4.4.0-96-generic
```

Finger touch event is in: `/dev/inpu/event16`

when use `evtest /dev/input/event16`, it seems work and send some data to that event by finger touch

but when I use `xinput test 14` there is no response in it.

Is there any way to fix this?

Additional Info:

```
xinput --list-props 14
Device 'Wacom Serial Penabled 2FG Touchscreen Finger touch':
    Device Enabled (139):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (264): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (265):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (266):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (267):    10.000000
    Device Node (261):  "/dev/input/event16"
    Wacom Tablet Area (329):    0, 0, 26312, 16520
    Wacom Rotation (330):   0
    Wacom Pressurecurve (331):  0, 0, 100, 100
    Wacom Serial IDs (332): 227, 0, 3, 0, 0
    Wacom Serial ID binding (333):  0
    Wacom Pressure Threshold (334): 0
    Wacom Sample and Suppress (335):    2, 4
    Wacom Enable Touch (336):   1
    Wacom Enable Touch Gesture (338):   1
    Wacom Touch Gesture Parameters (339):   1156, 513, 250
    Wacom Tool Type (340):  "TOUCH" (347)
    Wacom Button Actions (341): "Wacom button action 0" (342), "Wacom button action 1" (343), "Wacom button action 2" (344)
    Wacom button action 0 (342):    1572865
    Wacom button action 1 (343):    1572866
    Wacom button action 2 (344):    1572867
    Device Product ID (260):    1386, 227
    Wacom Debug Levels (346):   0, 0
```

AND

```
dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    2.507135] 00:04: ttyS4 at I/O 0x280 (irq = 6, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    2.529470] 0000:00:16.3: ttyS5 at I/O 0x4090 (irq = 17, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[   17.377222] serio: Serial port ttyS4
[   17.667974] input: Wacom Serial Penabled 2FG Touchscreen Pen as /devices/pnp0/00:04/tty/ttyS4/serio5/input/input21
[   17.669106] input: Wacom Serial Penabled 2FG Touchscreen Finger as /devices/pnp0/00:04/tty/ttyS4/serio5/input/input22
```

nothing happened when use

```
sudo screen /dev/ttyS5
```

And Also:

```
sudo screen /dev/ttyS4
[screen is terminating]
```

AND Xorg version:
    Xorg -version

```
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-89-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
```

Xorg Config directory:

```
ls /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
    10-amdgpu.conf  
    10-quirks.conf    
    11-evdev-trackpoint.conf
    50-vmmouse.conf
    51-synaptics-quirks.conf
    10-evdev.conf
    11-evdev-quirks.conf
    50-synaptics.conf    
    50-wacom.conf
```

Comment: I found problem in linux kernel, 16.04 has some problems with wacom w8001 driver which made it unusable.
I'v tried 15.10 and it worked,
this touch by16.04.0, 16.04.1,16.04.2 in fresh install doesn't work, and i'll try with 16.04.3 LTS Fresh install i hope it work.

Comment: i solve this problem by upgrade my kernel to 4.10.0-35-generic.
and dist-upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Only type this command `xsetwacom --set "<Your Tablet Model>" Touch on` 
so for me for instance, the command is `xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos Pro L Finger touch" Touch on`

For me it worked so it should work for you too.

Thank Me later ;D

Comment: Should this also work for turning **off** touch screen on tablets? How did you find your Tablet Model? I struggle to be able to [turn off the touch while keeping on the Pen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/756097/additional-udev-rule-to-keep-wacom-stylus-turned-on-while-disabling-touchscreen). Can you help?